# Why does the emf depends on the material of the electrodes? Why is the emf independent of the distance between electrodes and amount of electrolyte?

Tags: batteries, emf

Concise Physics mentions that:

> The emf (electromotive force)of a cell depends on 1) the material of the electrodes and 2)the electrolytes used in the cell.However it is independent of the a)the shape of electrode ,b)the distance between the electrodes and c) the amount of electrolyte in the cell

But the book doesn't explain anything' why the above things happens so. So I searched on the internet but I couldn't found any useful insights. My questions are as following

1. How does the emf(electromotive force) of a cell depends on the material of the electrodes?
   2)If the distance between the electrodes increases then more energy would have to be supplies by the battery for a unit charge to move towards the another electrode(terminal of the cell). But the book mentions otherwise. It tells that emf is independent of distance between the electrodes. So my second question is how emf can be independent of the distance between the electrodes?
   3)If the amount of electrolyte in a cell gets increased then certainly the volume of electrolyte would also increase and as a result the charges would have to travel a greater distance to reach the other electrode and therefore more energy per unit area would have to be supplied by the battery. But the books mentions the opposite (emf is independent of the amount of electrolyte) . So my third question is how emf is independent of the amount of electrolyte ?

At last the book mentions that emf depends on the electrolyte used in cell. So I thought of this Statement as:
If the electrons find it harder to travel across an electrolyte in comparison to another electrolyte then certainly more energy would have to be supplied by the battery to the charges in order to cross the electrolyte in comparison to another electrolyte in the cell. Is my thinking on this matter correct or have I misunderstood anything?

Comment: In a word, it's the chemistry, and that doesn't depend on the size of any of the components.

Answer (score 3):

The half-cell potential emf develops very locally, right at the surface interface between the electrode and the electrolyte. That's why the effect is independent of the mass of electrolyte or the mass of electrode. There is one half-cell potential developed across the entire surface interface area between the anode electrode and the electrolyte, and another half-cell potential developed across the entire surface area between the electrolyte and the cathode electrode.

The size and shape of the electrodes, and the mass of the electrolyte solution, do have effects on the battery cell performance in other ways -- the internal resistance will be lower if the electrode has more area; the capacitance between the electrodes depends on the electrode area and distance; the amount of energy that the cell can deliver to a load is affected, etc. But the open-circuit voltage only depends on the type of materials.

In terms of ideal lumped-constant models, the half-cell potential looks like an ideal voltage source connected between the electrode and the electrolyte. Using a larger area electrode, one could imagine multiple ideal voltage sources connected in parallel, but because they are in parallel the voltage is the same.

I also see here another common misconception about electricity, "more energy would have to be supplies by the battery for a unit charge to move towards the another electrode" -- the actual energy delivery phenomenon by electricity is a wavefront that involves the interaction of multiple electrons. The drift velocity of an electron is very slow, while the velocity of the wavefront is very fast (typically 2/3 c in most practical wiring systems).

There's not a lot of "why" answers in science, only experimental observations about "how" the effects are observed in nature.